# SEO markup for News article

Tags: seo, markup, articles

I implemented the following SEO markup on news article pages (around article text): `<div class="articleBody" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/NewsArticle">`

Is this implementation enough? Is this good for SEO?

On other sites I see
`<html lang="it" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/NewsArticle">` 
or
`<script type="application/ld+json">` with `"@context": "https://schema.org", "@type": "NewsArticle"`

So I am not sure if my implementation is correct or needs to be changed.

Comment: Did you test your page with https://search.google.com/test/rich-results

Comment: Are you trying to get included in Google News?

Answer (score 2):

I should note at the outset of this answer that individual preferences may vary and there may be others here who would like to advocate very strongly for `Microdata`.

But my direct experience (having worked with both `JSON-LD` and `Microdata` *and* `RDFa`) is that - in the interests of future maintainability, not least - if you are currently making an early decision as to use either `Microdata` (or `RDFa`) or `JSON-LD`, I would *definitely* lean towards `JSON-LD`.

In future, you (or other maintainers) will want to make changes to your Semantic Data at some point.

Consequently, keeping your Semantic Data separated from - rather than interwoven with - your Markup is a sensible choice. (No less sensible than keeping your CSS and your JS separated from your HTML).

Additionally, it's (arguably) much more straightforward to update `JSON` computationally than it is `HTML + Microdata`. And computational updates can often be faster, more efficient and more accurate than handwritten updates.

If you *do* decide to go with `JSON-LD` rather than `Microdata`, the example of `NewsArticle` at **schema.org** is a textbook example:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
       "@context": "https://schema.org",
       "@type": "NewsArticle",
       "url": "http://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-39324587",
       "publisher":{
          "@type":"Organization",
          "name":"BBC News",
          "logo":"http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/special/2015/newsspec_10857/bbc_news_logo.png?cb=1"
       },
       "headline": "Trump Russia claims: FBI's Comey confirms investigation of election 'interference'",
       "mainEntityOfPage": "http://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-39324587",
       "articleBody": "Director Comey says the probe into last year's US election would assess if crimes were committed.",
       "image":[
          "http://ichef-1.bbci.co.uk/news/560/media/images/75306000/jpg/_75306515_line976.jpg",
          "http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/560/cpsprodpb/8AB9/production/_95231553_comey2.jpg",
          "http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/560/cpsprodpb/17519/production/_95231559_committee.jpg",
          "http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/560/cpsprodpb/CC81/production/_95235325_f704a6dc-c017-4971-aac3-04c03eb097fb.jpg",
          "http://ichef-1.bbci.co.uk/news/560/cpsprodpb/11AA1/production/_95235327_c0b59f9e-316e-4641-aa7e-3fec6daea62b.jpg",
          "http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/560/cpsprodpb/0F99/production/_95239930_trumptweet.png",
          "http://ichef-1.bbci.co.uk/news/560/cpsprodpb/10DFA/production/_95241196_mediaitem95241195.jpg",
          "http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/560/cpsprodpb/2CA0/production/_95242411_comey.jpg",
          "http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/560/cpsprodpb/11318/production/_95242407_mediaitem95242406.jpg",
          "http://ichef-1.bbci.co.uk/news/560/cpsprodpb/BCED/production/_92856384_line976.jpg",
          "http://ichef-1.bbci.co.uk/news/560/cpsprodpb/12B64/production/_95244667_mediaitem95244666.jpg"
       ],
       "datePublished":"2017-03-20T20:30:54+00:00"
    }
</script>
```

**Source:** https://schema.org/NewsArticle